# Perguntas fechadas deveriam sair da página inicial

Tags: debate, perguntas, fechamento

Perguntas que foram fechadas não contribuem nada para a comunidade. Elas passaram por uma devida análise e foram fechadas por não estarem de acordo com as regras e princípios desta comunidade.

Mas, quando uma pergunta é fechada, ela permanece na página inicial, sendo inútil, poluindo a lista com conteúdo dispensável. Uma ideia seria remover essas perguntas do nosso "mostruário" e permitir que perguntas com possível potencial sejam de fato encontradas e respondidas.

**Mas e como vamos votar para reabrir?** Existe uma fila de análise justamente para perguntas que foram votadas para reabertura. Mas o que indica, é que ao serem votadas para reabrir, raramente são reabertas de fato, pela razão dela persistir com o mesmo ou diferente problema.

Além disso, um filtro de *"Mostrar perguntas fechadas"* também resolveria o problema.

Comment: Existe o voto para pergunta fechada ser ou não excluída, [veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Também temos as ferramentas para caçar perguntas e respostas com problemas veja a [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDJta.png) e [link para ferramenta de moderação(não é acessível a todos)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools)

Comment: Complementando o que o @AugustoVasques disse, só pra constar, logo você chega nos 10k e verá várias opções de moderação que ainda não tem (não diretamente específico à sua pergunta, falo de moderação em geral).